# How to sort tabs and set tab text

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I'm using the pyside designer as well as coding from the python file. I know I can use setTabText(index, text) to set a tab text but I want to set a tab text for a tab by object name. Also, is there a way to set a tab text when creating the tab? Also, is it possible to put the tabs on the left instead of the top? Like from top to bottom on the left side instead of left to right.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not provide a working code example I will give you a just-explanation answer with no code.

First, set tab by object name: you need to find your object by name using `tab = yourTabWidget.findChild(QWidget,"your-object-name")` then using `yourTabWidget.indexOf(tab)` you get the index of your tab an finally use `setTabText(index, text)` as you already know. Also when you add or insert the tabs you can provide as a second parameter the name as in `yourTabWidget.addTab(yourNewTab, "the-title-of-the-tab")`

Second, yes, yo can put your tabs to the left using: `yourTabWidget.setTabPosition(QtGui.QTabWidget.West)`